Surface Pro 9: how to activate Windows 11 Pro
There is a Surface Pro 9 tablet.
The original Windows on it has been Windows 11 Home. But, a repair shop has installed Windows 11 Pro on it, which needs activation.
How to install the original Windows 11 Home which won't need any activation? What's the standard way to do so?
A repair shop repaired the tablet recently. It's activation is messed up after the repair:

When it is tried to activate the Windows, the following error is received:

How is it possible to activate Windows?

Pretty sure that the surface pros came with Pro - but if it came with home, just installing home should pick up on the digitial entitlement it had before

@JourneymanGeek Thanks. Let me try.

This question is similar to: Force installation of Pro, Enterprise or other editions of Windows from 24H2 onwards. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Ramhound The question is edited. Thanks.

@JourneymanGeek for some time Microsoft split the Surface line between business and consumer. Only business tablets get Windows Pro by default, they're the same tablet, just different OS versions. I'm not sure when they started doing that, but it is at least since the Surface Pro 7.

@Megidd you may have to reinstall using a Surface recovery image for your device. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/surface/creating-and-using-a-usb-recovery-drive-for-surface-677852e2-ed34-45cb-40ef-398fc7d62c07 you will need the serial number for your device which should be under the kickstand if I remember correctly. I don't think there is a way to downgrade from Pro to Home.

The first answer seems promising (even if its for 10): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/downgrade-from-windows-10-pro-to-home/345f5464-cb7a-44b3-8856-237cbec072c8

There is no way to activate this key except for buying a windows 11 Pro key. You can use  the link provided by Mokubai or this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-recovery-image to find a suitable recovery image for your surface.

@Megidd - It's still a duplicate.  You asked how to activate Windows 11 Professional on a machine that came with Windows 11 Home.  The answer to the duplicate explains that process. You will have to reinstall Windows 11 Home, since you do NOT, have a Windows 11 Professional license.

@Ramhound Alright. Thanks. It makes sense now.

First you need to have the .iso image of the Windows 11 Home install sources.
Then you can create a bootable USB stick from that .iso file using Rufus.
To boot it you need to allow booting from USB. These settings can be accessed by powering on the Surface Pro while keeping the Volume Up key pressed. In some cases you may need to also temporarily disable Safe Boot.
Then boot from USB and reinstall the operating system.
Afterwards make sure to put the settings back as they were (disable booting from USB and enable Safe Boot again).

Surfaces come with special downloadable recovery images (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surface-recovery-image). It is the preferred way to restore a surface if normal windows recovery options fail.
